# Sort Images in while loop (no mysqli)

Tags: php, sorting, while-loop, opendir, readdir

I want to get picture from few sub-folder in a directory and i want to sort them as data. with the Following code I got the images now i want to sort them as data.

**Note**

every image name starts with the date and time of uploading example :-

default image name = "**image.jpg**"

after upload image name = "**24-02-2016-09-42-33-image.jpg**"

```
<?php
    $dir = 'dist/userdata/'.$username.'/photos/';

    if ($opendir = opendir ($dir) ) {

      $files = 0;

      while (($file = readdir ($opendir)) !== false && $files <= 2 + 1 ) {

        if ($file !="." && $file !="..") {

          $newdir = $dir.''.$file.'/';

          if ($newopendir = opendir ($newdir)) {
            $imgs = 0;
            while (($img = readdir ($newopendir)) !== false && $imgs <= 3 + 1) {
              if ($img !=="." && $img !=="..") {

                $supported_files = array(
                  'jpeg',
                    'jpg',
                    'png'
                );
                $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($img, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); 
                if (in_array($ext, $supported_files)) {
                  echo '<img src="'.$newdir.''.$img.'"/>';
                } else {
                }
              }
              $imgs++;
            }
          }

        }
        $files++;
      }
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: is there an actual question here? or do you just want someone to write the code for you?  also, what do you mean by "sort as data"?

Comment: if you mean "sort by filename", natsort() would probably serve you well - http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php

Comment: with the above code i am getting images from sub-folders of a directory the code is working (i am getting images) but sorted by filename. I want them to sort by date mean last uploaded image on the top.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of echoing images imidiatelly, gather them into array.
After that you can easily sort them with [usort()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.usort.php)

Also - you are not closing handles after opening them.

And, probably [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/recursivedirectoryiterator.construct.php) would be better fit for this than nested whiles.